# How to add previous data with new one in firebase realtime database javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
function add(){
  firebase.database().ref("user/l6xetRv3ddhjlerJm10d3aYkF3w1" ).update({            
    points: "2000"
  })
}
```

I am using this code above to update a specified user points for test but I want to update points of currently logged in user. I tried doing it on function onAuthStateChanged block, but it was unsuccessful. Any suggestions how should I do it?

And is it possible to update previous points adding with current update points? for example:- the previous points of user is 2000, the update function updates 2000 points but i want it to update previous points + current points which is goona be update (2000+2000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the points of the currently sign in user:

```
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref("user").child(uid).update({            
  points: "2000"
})
```

To increment/decrement the points of the user, you can use the [atomic increment operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments):

```
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref("user").child(uid).update({            
  points: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(2000);
})
```

Note that this will only work if you've stored the points as a number though, so:

```
firebase.database().ref("user").child(uid).update({            
  points: 2000 //  without quotes
})
```

And then

```
firebase.database().ref("user").child(uid).update({            
  points: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(2000);
})
```

Comment: It adds new value i want the increment to be added with older value.

Comment: Any Way to add older value plus new value?

Comment: Did you try the second snippet, and read the associated documentation I linked?

Comment: It's out of question but is there any way I can compare the points in my database and points needed and execute the task? Like if the user have 100 points in database but it is required 200 points to carry out an operation on web app is it possible to do so?

Comment: I showed how to do that with a transaction on your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71483949/how-can-i-compare-firebase-realtime-database-data-child-values/71485061?noredirect=1#comment126349272_71485061